# Java 8 group List of Lines so adjecent lines are together

Tags: java-8, stream

I have a list of lines where line is represented by two points.

Eg

```
public class Line {
    String start;
    String end
}
```

The list looks like `[P1, P2], [P2, P3], [P10, P11], [P11, P12], [P12, P13]` etc

I wasnt to group these adajcent lines together. `[[[P1, P2], [P2, P3]], [[P10, P11], [P11, P12], [P12, P13]]]`

How to do this with Java 8 `streams`. I tried `collect`, `reduce` and `groupBy` but couldn't quite get it done.

P.S

Got it done like below. Not very readable though

```
    private static List<List<LineDetailsTO>> groupOverlappingMultipartLines(List<LineDetailsTO> overlappingMultipartLines){
    List<List<LineDetailsTO>> grouped = overlappingMultipartLines.stream()
            .collect(Collector.of(ArrayList::new, (groupedLines, currentLine) -> {
                if(groupedLines.isEmpty()) {
                    groupedLines.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(currentLine)));
                } else {
                    List<LineDetailsTO> lastGroup = groupedLines.get(groupedLines.size() - 1);
                    LineDetailsTO lastLine = lastGroup.get(lastGroup.size() - 1);
                    if(lastLine.getEnd().equals(currentLine.getStart())){
                        lastGroup.add(currentLine);
                    } else {
                        groupedLines.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(currentLine)));
                    }
                }
            }, (left, right) -> {left.addAll(right); return left;}));

    return grouped;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem trivial though, but to clarify further, would `[P1,P2]`, `[P2,P3]` and `[P3,P4]` all be a part of the same line? `groupBy` could be of help only if there would be some unique identifier for points represented in a line. Having said that, an iterative implementation would make things clear in terms of what you are expecting as an outcome.

Comment: @Naman yes. They are part of the same line. I actually got this working with a collector but it is not very readable.

Comment: Great, freel free to modify the question accordingly in case you think a better solution might exist.